# How to work with Firebase cloud messaging OR conditions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 instance IDs registered. 1st one is subscribed to topic dogs and 2nd one is subscribed to topic cats.

I have tried to use the given example https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging#build_send_requests

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' {
    "notification": {
        "title": "FCM Message",
        "body": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    },
    "condition": "'dogs' in topics || 'cats' in topics"
}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1
```

After I ran this cURL I didn't got any errors nor did I got any notifications

```
{
    "name": "projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages/7533715453624815804"
}
```

If I send notification to exact topic or exact instance id it works, but not with OR condition.

Is here some rules that does not allow to use only OR without AND or is here something else I missed?